# Can model averaging be applied on models fitted to different data sets?

Tags: mixed-model, model-averaging

I have two data sets collected from two different sets of participants on their behaviour. 
EDIT: Both have the same response variables (Propensity to behave in a certain way - Yes or No). But they have some common (sex, age) and some different explanatory variables (education, origin etc) because they were two different surveys and two different set of participants. I have fitted generalised linear mixed effects models (GLMM) with participant ID as random effect separately for these data sets.

Why I would like to apply model averaging here is because I would like to take all the available information into my model from both data sets rather than fitting separate models for the two data sets.

Can I apply model averaging for the best Generalised Linear Mixed-effects models selected from the two different data sets or is it applied only for nested models?

Edit: What I mean by model averaging is averaging across model parameters instead of selecting one best model so that the model uncertainty issue can be addressed. (Eg: AIC and BIC-based model averaging - where weights are applied to the parameters, (Bates and Granger 1969),  Bayesian model averaging (BMA) (Raftery et al. 1997))

Thanks!

Comment: Please clarify any acronyms you use in your posts.  What GLMM stands for in your post might stand for something entirely different for someone else.

Comment: @StatsStudent I have edited that. Thanks for pointing out

Comment: Define "model averaging".

Comment: @user297451 What I mean by model averaging is averaging across model parameters instead of selecting one best model so that the model uncertainty issue can be addressed.

Comment: Could you still clarify the nature of the data a bit:  do the sets of participants differ somehow? Is the response "yes and no" the same question? Why are the covariates partially different between the datasets? (These details might matter)

Comment: @ Juho Kokkala - Yes, the response is for the same question. The covariates partially vary because they are from two different surveys with different participant IDs.